# How to convert a character to string in swift?

Tags: swift, casting, type-conversion

I wanted to perform a if condition for each character in a string, the string consists of digits and alphabets so I want to separate digits by using if condition, so how to extract each character and add it to another string
I've tried to convert using

```
NSString
```

But even then It didn't work 
so is there anything like

```
toInt()
```

Comment: `toInt()` for a character? What do you have, what do want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast directly to swift String:

```
let c : Character = "c"
let str = String(c)
```

You can not access a character at a index of string with str[index], you have to access by a Range. If you want to access this way, add a subscript extension to String:

```
extension String {
    subscript (index: Int) -> Character {
        return self[advance(self.startIndex, index)]
    }
}
```

then, you can call:

```
let myString = "abcdef"
let c: Character  = myString[1] //return 'b'
```